# Wrong URL's in ApiPlatform

Tags: symfony, api-platform.com

I've added ApiPlatform to my Symfony project. I've set up a custom provider, since the data lives in an external web service.

Here is my Entity:

```
<?php

namespace App\Entity;

use ApiPlatform\Metadata\ApiResource;
use ApiPlatform\Metadata\Get;
use ApiPlatform\Metadata\Post;
use App\State\CustomerProcessor;
use App\State\CustomerProvider;

#[ApiResource]
#[Post(processor: CustomerProcessor::class)]
#[Get(provider: CustomerProvider::class)]
class Customer
{
    #[Id]
    public string $customerId;

}
```

And here's my `provide()` method in the provider:

```
    public function provide(Operation $operation, array $uriVariables = [], array $context = []): object|array|null
    {
        // create a Customer object to return
        return new Customer();
    }
```

I'm missing a route definition for /api/customers/{id}, and also, the route /api/customers is set up to return a single resource.

[image]

Why is that?

Answer (score 2):

To treat /customers as an endpoint for the collection, decorate the entity class:

```
#[ApiResource(
    operations: [
        new Get(provider: CustomerProvider::class),
        new GetCollection(provider: CustomerProvider::class)
    ]
)]
class Customer
{
 ...
}
```

And to fix the issue with the individual resource path, add this decoration to the identifier instead:

```
#[ApiProperty(identifier: true)]
```

Then clear the cache!